# Swift OSX Audio pass thru while recording

Tags: swift, macos, core-audio, audio-recording

I'm programming in Xcode 9 - swift 4 - macOS NOT IOS

I have a basic recording audio setup below for recording a singer with headphones and a microphone. I would like it to react like Logic X.

In Logic X you put the track you want to record into record ready while this happens the microphone is routed to the headphones so the vocalist can hear himself/herself. Whilst in playback the record ready is muted so the vocalist can here whats been recorded. and if the record button is pressed during playback then the vocalist hears the vocal being recorded.

The problem i am having is routing audio in directly to audio out. I'm not quiet sure what Audio system I should use AVAudioSession is obviously for iOS
. Do i have to go to Core Audio. I would like to stick with swift 4

Any advice would be appreciated

here is what i have so far

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

enum RecordingPreset: Int {
    case Low = 0
    case Medium
    case High

    func settings() -> Dictionary<String, Int> {
        switch self {
        case .Low:
            return [AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16, AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1, AVSampleRateKey : 12_000, AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey : 0, AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey : 0]

        case .Medium:
            return [AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16, AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1, AVSampleRateKey : 24_000, AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey : 0, AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey : 0]

        case .High:
            return [AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16, AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1, AVSampleRateKey : 48_000, AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey : 0, AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey : 0]
        }
    }

    func exportSettings() -> Dictionary <String, Int> {

        var recordingSetting = self.settings()
        recordingSetting[AVFormatIDKey] = Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM)
        recordingSetting[AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved] = 0
        return recordingSetting
    }
}//eo RecordingPreset



extension Array {
    func firstObject() -> Element? {
        var firstObject: Element?
        if self.count > 0 {
            firstObject = self[0]
        }
        return firstObject
    }

    func lastObject() -> Element? {
        var lastObject: Element?
        if self.count > 0 {
            lastObject = self[self.endIndex - 1]
        }
        return lastObject
    }
}

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {
    var audioEngine:AVAudioEngine!
    var player:AVAudioPlayer!
    var recorder: AVAudioRecorder?

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

    }//EO Overide

    func createRecorder() -> () {
        var initialisedRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?
        let currentDate = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yy HHmmss"
        let fileName = "/RECORDING/Audio/Recording on " + dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate as Date) + ".wav"
        let filePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        if let firstPath = filePaths.firstObject() {
            let recordingPath = firstPath + fileName
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: recordingPath)
            let selectedPreset = RecordingPreset.High
            do {
                initialisedRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: url as URL, settings: selectedPreset.settings()
                )
            }catch {
                print("nope")
            }
            initialisedRecorder!.isMeteringEnabled = true
            initialisedRecorder!.prepareToRecord()
        }
        recorder = initialisedRecorder
    }//eo createRecorder



    @IBAction func myRecord(_ sender: Any) {
        print("RECORD")
        createRecorder()
        recorder?.record()
    }


    @IBAction func myStop(_ sender: Any) {
        print("STOP")
        recorder?.stop()
        recorder = nil
    }



}//EnD oF thE wORld
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AVFoundation framework instead of Core Audio directly.  For pass-thru audio, you can create a custom V3 AUAudioUnit subclass, and pass data from the instantiated audio object's input renderblock to its output buffer (perhaps using a circular FIFO), and with fairly low latency.

Note that Apple (in a 2017 WWDC session on Core Audio) recommended not using Swift or Objective C methods inside the real-time audio context, so you may need to write a tiny portion (the buffer copy) in C.